# Facing an issue in jmeter while hitting through aws load balancer

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, jmeter, wildfly

1. I am trying to test a api with the help of jmeter through aws load balancer it throws 504.And the instance cpu reached 100% and it is not getting drop till restarting the server.
2. Same api tested with the help of postman through aws load balancer it throws the expected output.
3. Same api tested with the help of jmeter hitting directly to the instance(voilated load balancer) throws the expected outupt.

I am facing the issue only hitting via load balancer through JMETER.
I am not facing the issue 
  While hitting via load balancer through postman 
  Hitting without load balancer directly to the instance through JMETER.
so how to overcome the issue with jmeter and loadbalancer

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a [DNS Cache Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#DNS_Cache_Manager) to your Test Plan, it might be the case that JMeter hits only one node behind the load balancer and remaining nodes are not touched by the load test.

References:

- [Disable DNS caching](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0445.html)
- [The DNS Cache Manager: The Right Way To Test Load Balanced Apps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dns-cache-manager-right-way-test-load-balanced-apps)

Other causes could be connected with load balancing mechanism and/or algorithm, the load balancer can orchestrate the requests basing on cookies so you will need to play with the [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager), or source IP address or whatever.